# Django Userena Extending

Tags: django, django-models, django-users

I am trying to implement the concept of "Plans" (free, pro, enterprise, etc.) when a user signs up for my site.

I am beginning `Python` & `Django`. I've gotten `django-userena` installed and working. Now, I am trying to extend the behavior to allow a user to select a "Plan" when signing up for the site.

I believe the plan would be stored in a subclass of `UserenaBaseProfile`, but not sure... maybe plan choice should not be part of the profile.

What is the best way to implement the concept of "plans" in a `Django` app using `Userena` (or not using `Userena`!).

Answer (score 2):

You can create a `Plan` model which holds all the plan details. After that create a `UserPlan` Model with the following fields.

```
user = models.OneToOneField(UserenaBaseProfile)
plan = models.ForeignKey(Plan)
// other fields like validity and audit related fields
```

It is easier to separate the user's plans details from the core models.

Answer (score 0):

I would make the plan levels into permissions.

If they need to be assigned to a particular object, you can use django-guardian to add them to the class for that object:

```
class Whatever(ExtendedGuardedModel, BaseModel):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    class Meta(BaseModel.Meta):
        permissions = (
            ("free", "Free level of access"),
            ("pro", "Pro level of access"),
            ("enterprise", "Enterprise level of access"),
        )
```

Then when you need to check the plan level of an account, you just use the typical way of checking permissions, except look for "free", "pro" etc.